# Angular Unit Testing Factory Injection

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've seen this answered but none of the solutions are working for me. I'm getting an error `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got undefined` which is causing my test to fail. What's the correct way to inject a factory into a test spec that isn't a stubbed factory.

***login module***

```
angular.module('loginModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'permission', 'ui.router', 'coreModule', 'utilsModule']);
```

***login controller***

```
  (function(){
      'use strict';

      angular.module('loginModule')
      .controller('loginController', login);

      login.$inject = [
          '$log',
          '$uibModal',
          '$rootScope',
          'storageFactory',
          'loginFactory',
          '$state',
          'RoleStore',
          'PermissionStore',
          'vsmsCoreFactory'
      ];

      function login($log, $uibModal, $rootScope, storageFactory, loginFactory, $state, RoleStore, PermissionStore, vsmsCoreFactory) {

          /* jshint validthis: true */
          var vm = this;
          vm.loginUser = loginUser;
          vm.forgotPassword = forgotPassword;
          vm.errorCode = null;
          PermissionStore.clearStore();
          vsmsCoreFactory.getHashFunction()
            .then(function(response) {
                if(response) {
                  storageFactory.setHashFunction(response); // unknown provider
              }
            });

          function loginUser() {
          ...
```

***login controller spec***

```
describe('loginController', function() {

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(module('loginModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('vm.loginUser', function() {
    it('should be defined', function() {
      var loginController = $controller('loginController');
      expect(loginController.loginUser).toBeDefined();
    });
  });

});
```

***unit test files***

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

var wiredep = require('wiredep');

var paths = gulp.paths;

function runTests (singleRun, done) {
  var bowerDeps = wiredep({
    directory: 'bower_components',
    exclude: ['bootstrap-sass-official'],
    dependencies: true,
    devDependencies: true
  });

  var testFiles = bowerDeps.js.concat([
    './src/components/scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-2.1.3.js',
    './src/app/index.js',
    './src/{app,components}/**/*.module.js',
    './src/{app,components}/**/*.factory.js',
    './src/{app,components}/**/*.controller.js',
    './src/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js'
  ]);

  gulp.src(testFiles)
    .pipe($.karma({
      configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
      action: (singleRun)? 'run': 'watch'
    }))
    .on('error', function (err) {
      // Make sure failed tests cause gulp to exit non-zero
      throw err;
    });
}

gulp.task('test', function (done) { runTests(true /* singleRun */, done) });
gulp.task('test:auto', function (done) { runTests(false /* singleRun */, done) });
```

***app***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('fotaAdminPortal',
    [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.router.stateHelper',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'utilsModule',
    'loginModule',
    ...
    ])
```

***log***

Chrome 54.0.2840 (Mac OS X 10.11.6) loginController vm.loginUser should be defined FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: storageFactoryProvider <- storageFactory <- loginController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fotaAdminPortal` module isn't loaded for the test so `vsmsCoreFactory` never gets registered.

Also there's no need to manually pass services into a controller as the injector will automatically do this when you create it. Passing services manually is useful when you need to pass something that isn't a globally registered service ie `$scope` or mock a service for a single controller instance.

Atm the mocks for the factories are just an undefined variable which will cause errors when the logic depending on them tries to call the methods that don't exist. You'll need to properly stub any methods on these mocks. But leaving those aside for the moment your test should be something like:

```
describe('loginController', function() {

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(module('fotaAdminPortal'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('vm.loginUser', function() {
      it('should be defined', function() {
        var loginController = $controller('loginController');
        expect(loginController.loginUser).toBeDefined();
      });
  });

});
```

If you want to load `loginModule` in isolation then you need to extract `vsmsCoreFactory` into another module and add that as a dependency:

```
angular.module('vsmsCore', [])
  .factory('vsmsCoreFactory', function($http, env, $log, storageFactory) {

  });

angular.module('loginModule', ['ui.bootstrap', 'permission', 'ui.router', 'vsmsCore']);
```

Then you can do `beforeEach(module('loginModule'))` instead

Comment: `fotaAdminPortal` is the main app module, which is loaded by karma ('./src/app/index.js'), as well as `vsmsCoreFactory` ('./src/{app,components}/**/*.factory.js'), as shown in unit test files. The karma logs also show that both the app file and the factory are loaded. `loginModule` is a dependency of `fotaAdminPortal`.

Comment: The file is loaded, but unless you boot up the module with `module(..)` then it's never registered. Problem is `loginModule` depends on services (`vsmsCoreFactory`) from the parent module so it's tightly coupled and can't be created in isolation. Either you boot the whole app or you extract the service into a separate module and add that as a dependency to `loginModule`

Comment: Ok, makes sense. I created a `coreModule` for the factory and added that as a dependency to `loginModule`, which fixed the issue of `vsmsCoreFactory` being undefined. Now, I'm seeing Unknown provider: storageFactoryProvider <- storageFactory <- loginController. `storageFactory` belongs to the `utilsModule`, which I've also defined as a `loginModule` dependency.